# How many master detail and lookup relationship can we create on an object in Winter 17 release?

Tags: administration, summer14

I know that there were 2 master detail and 25 look up relationship allowed until Summer 14 release!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are just asking this now so many releases later.

Neither of these limits has changed in the `Winter 17` release. The limit on `Master Detail` relationships is still 2, and the limit on `Lookup` relationships is still 40. You can see when this change was made for yourself in the [Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_additional.htm):

> **Increased Maximum Number of Relationship Fields**
>   The maximum number of Relationship Fields per object has been increased, from 25 fields to 40 fields.

Comment: Beaten to it - reference https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_features.htm

Comment: But keep in mind which direction this restriction is on. One object can only be the detail of a maximum of two masters. But there is no such limit on how many detail objects can point to one master object.

Comment: Yeah that's just the nature of how relationships work in Salesforce.